# MVC Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

can anyone explain me the real concept of doing unit testing for model classes.

```
public class category
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

In my test class, i saw people writing code like this

```
[TestClass]
public class CategoryTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Category_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        category = new Category() { intialisation};
        //Act

        //Assert
        check again you have same values are not;
    }
}
```

I couldn't see any value of testing model classes testing without interacting to databases?

Comment: That's a totally legitimate question, one answer is -- doing it this way is about the only way to check for misspelling errors (in isolation from other code, which will "test" it for us anyway). This probably does improve reliability in some sense, but only a tiny bit ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unit Testing - Wiki

> Unit testing is a method by which
>   individual units of source code are
>   tested to determine if they are fit
>   for use. A unit is the smallest
>   testable part of an application. In
>   procedural programming a unit may be
>   an individual function or procedure.
>   In object-oriented programming a unit
>   is usually a method. Unit tests are
>   created by programmers or occasionally
>   by white box testers during the
>   development process.

Unit tests will not use actual objects; it will be performed using [Mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

Answer (score 0):

@Anuraj is right, a great example project for all things MVC is Nerd Dinner 
http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/